# When performing anova analysis of a multiple regression model in R studio, how is the sum of square value of each explanatory variable calculated?

Tags: r, anova

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DG3z.png)]

I think it should be (SSE of reduced model - SSE of full model). If so, is the reduced model a model in which only each variable is removed? If not, how is it calculated? Please explain using the Agr variable as an example.

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4X8z.png)]

The SSE of the model with Agr removed was 0.5504. 0.5504 - 0.5188 = 0.0316, which is not 0.5590

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `anova` function in R performs a Type 1 ANOVA.  If you used `car::Anova(..,type=2)` it could perform a Type 2 ANOVA which would behave as you expect.

So in your case, because `Agr` is the first term entered, the sum of squares for `Agr` reported by `anova` is the difference in the SSE between the null model `Nitrogen~1` and the model with `Agr` alone as a predictor.

See here for more explanation https://www.r-bloggers.com/2011/03/anova-%E2%80%93-type-iiiiii-ss-explained/

Comment: Or you can use the builtin `drop1()` function for a type III (type II) ANOVA.